# Is there a way to deploy "n" amount of template kubernetes pods with different env parameters

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to make a k8s based cluster for http requests handling, based on the amount of plugged-in devices into the subnet.
I was not able to find any hints on how to make a dynamic pod invoke structure, based on env parameters (in this example device IPs) stored in a PV.
The scenario should be simple in theory - a pod should be deployed for every IP address in the container with the environment parameter of the device IP address. If if another devices IP is added into the PV, which is a remote container storage, another pod should be deployed based on the new IP.

Thank you in advance for the hints!

Comment: can you explain what `If another device is added into the container` means?

Comment: @rkosegi, thank you for the reply - it is a shortcut for the if another devices IP is added into the PV, which is a remote container storage.

Comment: You'd have to build this setup yourself, both the request-routing aspect of it and creating new Deployments on demand.  You might find the [operator pattern](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) helpful: you can write a program that listens for a custom Kubernetes resource and reacts to it to create other objects, and then store the external device IP addresses in Kubernetes objects rather than a flat file somewhere.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thank you for the hint - gonna try this now!